# How to fight unresolved variables warning in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I have a function which takes a data from ajax:

```
function test(str){
   var obj=JSON.parse(str);
   console.log(obj.xxx);
}
```

WebStorm says that `xxx` - is unresolved variable.
I can't use `@namespace`. So how can I do?

Comment: have you tried `var obj = str.json();`?

Comment: `str.json` is not a function

Comment: Could you provide the string being parsed?

Answer (score 0):

In cases when the actual data is only known at runtime (for example, when data is a value set through ajax call), it can't re resolved during static analysis, so the warnings are expected. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17419#comment=27-1058451, http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5504337#5504337 for possible workarounds.